Looking for a JavaScript library to interact with SharePoint lists using Javascript from a non-SharePoint website
I'm trying to use a SharePoint as a database to avoid needing a DBA (big company). Is there a library that would enable me to more easily interact with SharePoint lists from a static website using JavaScript (this is a 'modern' M365 site)?
Also, my company hasn't enabled the SharePoint App Catalog, so I can't publish any web parts using SPFx.

I found this library, but interested as to whether there are recommendations for anything newer/better.

The best choice is probably PnPJs! Great community, lot of changes, documentation and samples, etc.

PnPjs is a collection of fluent libraries for consuming SharePoint, Graph, and Office 365 REST APIs in a type-safe way. You can use it within SharePoint Framework, Nodejs, or any JavaScript project. This an open source initiative and we encourage contributions and constructive feedback from the community.

As your code will be outside any Microsoft application, you need to authenticate with MSAL, for example, with @pnp/msaljsclient or with JavaScript.

Thank you for this recommendation!
